# Как добавить таблицу в графический интерфейс приложения?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Возник небольшой вопрос - в интернете особо доходчивого ответа не нашел. Мне нужно написать программку на Win32 API, которая будет выдавать большой результат и его вывод (результата) надо оформить в таблицу вида Excel, примерно столбцов 10 и строк около 1000. Так как я не особо разбираюсь в интерфейсе, решил делать на MFC. Интересует, как создать таблицу, чтобы можно было работать с любой ячейкой, строкой и столбцом в ней. Кто подскажет, где можно найти литературу по этому вопросу или кто-то сам может объяснить?

Comment: Может ли кто указать на литературу с примером как использовать grid control на русском языке? или у кого то есть время и он может сам пример привести что бы понять мне как и что работает?

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта:

1. Найти готовый компонент (какой-нибудь MFC Grid Сontrol или вроде) и встроить его.
2. Подключить таблицы Excel через автоматизацию, если на систему установлен Excel.

Статьи по автоматизации есть в поддержке, например: [как внедрить и автоматизировать лист Microsoft Excel с MFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q184663/).